# Flutter - Numeric keyboard not working with Swiftkey

Tags: android, flutter, numeric-keypad

I have an app that uses Numeric Keyboard. I use `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` on the text field to set it to numeric, and it works, but only with the standard keyboard. When I run it on my phone and turn on Microsoft Swiftkey, it switches to the number page of the normal keyboard instead. And I do know that swiftkey does have numeric keyboard option because I have other apps that use it and it works, but mine doesn't trigger it.

What's the problem here?
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could simply be an issue with SwiftKey. I've used SwiftKey myself and have experienced many problems in almost all the apps that I use it on so this could simply be a problem with that software, not Flutter. SwiftKey unfortuantely is not an open-source software hence you cannot track bugs on GitHub.

Comment: It might be a swiftkey issue, but why the other apps can access the numeric keyboard but not flutter?